# TS2339: Property 'token' does not exist on type 'Response'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

loginservice.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {

  constructor() { }

  http = inject(HttpClient)

  onLoginAuthentication(obj:any): Observable<Response>{
    return this.http.post<Response>('https://fakestoreapi.com/auth/login', obj)
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { LoginService } from './login.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet, FormsModule],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})

export class AppComponent{
  title = 'myProject';

  username : string= ''
  password : string= ''

  service = inject(LoginService)

  onSubmit(){
    let obj = {
       username: this.username,
       password: this.password
    }
    this.service.onLoginAuthentication(obj).subscribe((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      sessionStorage.setItem('access_token', response.token);
    });
  }
}
```

Property 'token' does not exist on type 'Response'

The Response from the api is { token : "ajlsjdfflkjsdflk" }
Instead of any type which alternative type should i use here

Comment: Replace `Response` with a type you expect from your backend